# Query created from Power Query is not loading into excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to divide column A into 200 rows per column. I have managed to do it with WRAPCOLS(A2:A999999,200). The problem i have the end user is using an older version of excel. I can do it using INDEX(A2:A999999,ROW(A1)+(COLUMN(A1)-1)*200)), but i want to use the power query.

| Column A |
| --- |
| A1 |
| A2 |
| A3 |
| A4 |
| A5 |
| A6 |
| A7 |
| A8 |
| A9 |
| A10 |
| A11 |
| A12 |
| A13 |
| A14 |
| A15 |
| A16 |
| A17 |
| A18 |
| A19 |
| A20 |
| .... |
| A999999 |

[image]

but it keeps on loading, what I am doing wrong

I tried using Power Query

let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Custom1 = Table.FromRows(List.Split(Source[ID],200))
in
Custom1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Transposed Table" = Table.FromColumns(List.Split(Source[Column1],200))
in #"Transposed Table"
```

or

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
Divide = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Integer-Division", each Number.IntegerDivide([Index], 200), Int64.Type),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Divide, {"Integer-Division"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index2", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Column1", "Index2"}, {"Column1", "Index2"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Integer-Division", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Integer-Division", type text}}, "en-US")[#"Integer-Division"]), "Integer-Division", "Column1")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]